# How should I store persistent data in java web app?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, web-applications

I'm having some problems with my java web project. I mean, this project is something like course managing system. I fact, it's my first real project. And so, my problem is that I don't know how to store files (associated with specific course) that teacher uploads for his students. I thought about using a database (I'm using MySQL with Hibernate for persisting Teacher, Student and Course objects), but I'm not sure how to do it because the easiest way to link the files with appropriate Course would be with some List of them and I don't know if that's possible (because these files would need Blob). So, if it is, can you help me find a way to do it? And if it isn't, what should I do?

Comment: A blob is just a type . Thus, one can create, for example, a table `files` with a column `id` (e.g. an `INT`) and a column `file` (a `BLOB`). Then, one would link them through a join table. But I would advise against this approach, store the files in a known directory, re-naming them to, e.g., a `UUID` and only store the `UUID`s in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing files in a database is not a smart thing to do and will slow down the entire system once the number of records start growing.
Better approach will be something like:

- Create a service for downloading uploaded file in an existing directory and returning a UUID for the same (You  can use the timestamp and name of the file for this).
- Store the UUID in the database.